# Detecting server failure from logs

Tags: linux, memory, memory-leaks

I have a problem with my RPI that host a server software (light server), After amount of time the OS crashes with no option to reach it in any way, all processes is down, it's not discoverable via ssh or ping.
After a hard reset, I see the following information in the syslog:

```
00:23:21 my-rnd-machine kernel: [    0.000000] Memory: 940244K/970752K available (7168K kernel code, 575K rwdata, 2072K rodata, 1024K init, 706K bss, 22316K reserved, 8192K cma-reserved)
Apr 21 00:23:21 my-rnd-machine kernel: [    0.000000] Virtual kernel memory layout:
Apr 21 00:23:21 my-rnd-machine kernel: [    0.000000]     vector  : 0xffff0000 - 0xffff1000   (   4 kB)
Apr 21 00:23:21 my-rnd-machine kernel: [    0.000000]     fixmap  : 0xffc00000 - 0xfff00000   (3072 kB)
Apr 21 00:23:21 my-rnd-machine kernel: [    0.000000]     vmalloc : 0xbb800000 - 0xff800000   (1088 MB)
Apr 21 00:23:21 my-rnd-machine kernel: [    0.000000]     lowmem  : 0x80000000 - 0xbb400000   ( 948 MB)
Apr 21 00:23:21 my-rnd-machine kernel: [    0.000000]     modules : 0x7f000000 - 0x80000000   (  16 MB)
Apr 21 00:23:21 my-rnd-machine kernel: [    0.000000]       .text : 0x80008000 - 0x80800000   (8160 kB)
Apr 21 00:23:21 my-rnd-machine kernel: [    0.000000]       .init : 0x80b00000 - 0x80c00000   (1024 kB)
Apr 21 00:23:21 my-rnd-machine kernel: [    0.000000]       .data : 0x80c00000 - 0x80c8fef4   ( 576 kB)
Apr 21 00:23:21 my-rnd-machine kernel: [    0.000000]        .bss : 0x80c96f40 - 0x80d478b4   ( 707 kB)
```

I know this means that there is a memory leak somewhere.
I want to develop kind of a watchdog that monitor the amount of used memory.
I tried to run df command, free command and some more, but all of these commands are getting wrong number of free memory.
Does anyone have any idea on how to detect this leak before it reach the death line?